# When exporting from react native to ios project, the ios product name has special characters removed

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using npm 8.11.0 in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

I created a react native project using expo with the following app name (in App.json):

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Waku News", 
    "slug": ...
```

I export the react native project to android and ios project using `npm run eject`. I find that the app name in ios (under project.pbxproj) has the space removed.

```
/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */
        13B07F941A680F5B00A75B9A /* Debug */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            ...
            PRODUCT_NAME = "WakuNews";
            ...
```

But the app name in android project has no such issues:

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">Waku News</string>
  ...
</resources>
```

I tried to add "displayName" in App.json but no use:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Waku News", 
    "displayName": "Waku News",
    "slug": ...
```

I try other ways, like replacing the space with underscore "_", but the result is the same: The PRODUCT_NAME in ios project still have the space and underscore removed.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Waku_News", 
    "displayName": "Waku News",
    "slug": ...
```

My question is: how can I customize the app name in the react native project such that the PRODUCT_NAME in ios and app_name in android use the same values, without removing any spaces or special characters?